# To where should we redirect discussion questions?

Tags: discussion

Questions which are subjective or likely to end up as discussions rather than definitive answers get closed.

It would be nice to not just say bluntly "you can't discuss this here", but instead "you should try the ____ forum".

Answer (score 4):

http://www.eevblog.com --> Forum

Is my default comment if I start the close vote.
There's a lot of people there with opinions and a hunkering to discuss for 100's of pages about trivial things, so a poster can watch that happen with great glee.

Answer (score 3):

When the user has got 20 reputation, I recommend our [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't.  Doing so would encourage even more questions that don't belong here.

We are not the help desk for the rest of the internet.  Acting like one will only noise up the site and give a worse experience to those who came here for what the site is really for.

Put yet another way, your suggestion would help those that are abusing the site and breaking the rules at the expense of those that are trying to use the site properly.

**BAD IDEA.**